# Transform properties/variables clashing in sass and overwriting eachother

Tags: css, sass

I have the code at the bottom of the page in my sass. In my html I am targeting it as follows

```
class=" transform rotate-5 zoom-2 ......"
```

the problem is that the transform properties are clashing and aren't applying scale and rotate to the same div tag, I'm either getting one or the other. 
I thought I could change this by using the @extend property and something like,

```
&.rotate-#{$i}
 {@extend &.skew-#{$i}, &.zoom-#{$i}, &.zoom--#{$i};
            transform: rotate($rotate#{deg});
        }
```

but so far I've had no luck, if anyone can help it'd be greatly appreciated.

```
.transform {

    overflow:hidden;

    @for $i from 1 through 360 {

        $rotate: $i;
        $skew: $i;
        $zoom: $i;

        &.rotate-#{$i} {
            transform: rotate($rotate#{deg});
        }

        &.skew-#{$i} { 
            transform: skew($skew#{deg});
        }
        &.zoom-#{$i} { 
            transform: scale($zoom,0);
        }

        &.zoom--#{$i} { 
            transform: scale(-$zoom,0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of utility classes that I thought easier to debug and to build with. But here it doesn't seem to be a good idea:

1) You are creating 360 * 4 selectors, yet you will probably only use 10-20 of them. It is a bit overkill.

2) As you describe it, the transform property values do not "combine" well, at least for what you are looking for. Even [atomic CSS](https://acss.io/guides/atomic-classes.html), which pushes very far the utility classes approach, specificies that combining different values of `filter` (for instance) needs creating a custom value / class.

I understand that it is not really a good answer, at least not the answer you were looking for, but if you want to keep your CSS only approach, I suggest you adopt a more "object-oriented" method for this issue and set your transform property directly in the css of your object, for instance with this mixin:

```
@mixin transform($rotate, $skew, $zoom) {
  transform: rotate($rotate#{deg}) skew($skew#{deg}) scale($zoom,0) scale(-$zoom,0);
}
```